# Qt remove regular expression from string

Tags: qt, qstring, qregexp

I have a QString that I have replaced "=" and"," with " ". Now I would like to write a regular expression that would remove every occurrence of a certain string followed immediately by parenthesis containing a 1 to 2 character long number. 
For Example: "mat(1) = 5, mat(2) = 4, mat(3) = 8" would become "5 4 8"

So this is what I have so far:

```
text = text.replace("=", " "); 
text = text.replace(",", " "); 
text = text.remove( QRegExp( "mat\([0-9]{1,2}\)" ) );
```

The regular expression is not correct, how can I fix it to do what i want? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes for C++ string literals:

```
text = text.remove( QRegExp( "mat\\([0-9]{1,2}\\)" ) );
```

Comment: this does not work for me. the original backslashes I have are for that purpose. Did you try this and it worked?

Comment: Just realized I was wrong! This did work, I just had to make sure to specify that it was not case insensitive to catch MAT at well. THANKS!